# Deadlock due to keylock and page lock in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, deadlock, database-deadlocks

We are facing deadlock for 2 to 3 times a day. When we analysed it is due to keylock and pagelock happening together.

We found deadlock is between the database replication job and other ETL job

Keylock is owned as Exclusive lock (x) by the database replication job on the clustered index column, and when ETL process is trying to get shared lock (s) on the same index it is failing as victim.

The page lock is owned by the ETL process as shared lock (s) and the replication job is getting an Intent Exclusive lock (ix) on the same.

When we try re-running the failed ETL job after some time it is getting completed. ETL job has only select query and no updates, inserts or deletes. It is only truncate and load. Further it is not happening in all jobs which is hitting the same server, only few jobs are getting failed. The replication job is set to run all the time.

Will `SELECT(NO LOCK)` help in this case? Or increasing the deadlock priority of ETL job?

Could anyone help how to resolve this deadlock?

Comment: You need to provide your deadlock graph - the XML file. Deadlocks can be fairly tricky to resolve - you may need to spend the time to understand them in order to fix them.

Comment: I think you obfuscated the bits of info we need. I forgot we also need the queries which cause the deadlock, but for sure we need to know the objects involved.

Comment: But probably the best thing is for you to understand what is happening, the typical deadlock is 2 processes using the same 2 resources but in a different order, and they reach a point where process 1 needs resource B while holding a lock on resource A, and process 2 needs resource A while holding a lock on resource B, and as there is no way forward its a deadlock. So you need to identify how that applies to you. Sometimes you can change the order resources are acquired, sometimes you can add indexes which prevent the situation in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes you can deliberately obtain a specific lock on a resource earlier in the process to ensure the order locks are taken is the same.